# When using preg_replace only use $1 (in the replacement) if $2 doesn't exist

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am currently using this snippet to change the text from `[[foo]]`to a full HTML `a` link.

```
$var = preg_replace('/\[\[((.*?)(\|(.*?))?)\]\]/', '<a href="https://foobar.com/$1">$1</a>', $var);
```

However, when a piped parameter, such as `[[foo|bar]]`, is used the `a` link should look like this

```
<a href="https://foobar.com/$1">$2</a>
```

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to figure out how to handle this, hoping y'all will be able to help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) and test for the existence of your second match within the callback (fall back to the first match if it doesn't exist):

```
$var = '[[foo|bar]]';

$var = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[\[(?<uri>.*?)(?:\|(?<text>.*?))?]]/',

    static function (array $matches): string {
        $uri = $matches['uri'];
        $text = $matches['text'] ?? $uri;

        return "<a href=\"https://foobar.com/{$uri}\">{$text}</a>";
    },

    $var
);

echo $var;  // <a href="https://foobar.com/foo">bar</a>
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fltuR)**

Note: I took the liberty of slightly altering/optimizing your regex (remove undesired capturing parentheses, backslashes, and add some named captures).

Comment: @penguinstyles Any reason you unchecked this answer?